# Launcher labels have red background

Tags: unity, compiz, unity-dash

I've recently migrated to Ubuntu from Windows 7 and it's been great so far. I have this one problem though that I cannot solve. On the right side of the screen where my icons/shortcuts (launcher) are, when hovering the mouse above them the tags that appear next to them are red. Sort of graphics problem. And when I click Dash home it doesn't open. Although I do see the min/max/close buttons at the top I see nothing else.
I've already tried resetting Unity, removing it, install, re-install etc...

Pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the issue? It's hard to understand from your description. Upload the image to a service like http://imgur.com and paste the link into your question. Also, please mention the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: I've added the screenshot

Comment: You are using 12.04? what is your graphics card and graphics driver?  Have you tried running 14.04 from a USB stick to see if this is resolved?

Comment: When I log in as a guest I do not have that problem. everything works as expected. I have onboard graphics. Lenovo G550

Comment: It looks like you are running Unity 2D, is that on purpose?
Did you install any graphics driver via the "Additional Drivers" app?

Comment: I do not know if I did this on purpose. After installation I only installed the broadcom wireless driver. Nothing more. From what I remember I did mess with this a while back

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2028896/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7.html

Could this have created the problem?

Comment: Not really sure, did you try their first method that changes Unity itself? and did you undo the changes like they suggested?

Comment: Yes, I've tried everything. Still no luck. But when I log in as guest Unity works properly though. I don't know if this will help.

Comment: Are you running Unity 2D in the guest account?

Comment: I run the default. I think it is not the 2d.